# Select Item in Wrappanel or list based on X and Y cordinates

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, leap-motion

I have a wrap panel with images in it. I am using a pointing device and can get X and Y coordinates on screen. I would like to use the X and Y coordinates to select a particular item in the WrapPanel or List.

```
<WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Name="ImageWrap">
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource imageContainerStyle}">
        <Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="/Images/Texture01.jpg" />
    </ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource imageContainerStyle}">
        <Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="/Images/Texture02.jpg" />
    </ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource imageContainerStyle}">
        <Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="/Images/Texture03.jpg" />
    </ContentControl>
</WrapPanel>
```

C# code which I am trying to use. But isn't working

```
Point mousePosition = new Point(xPosition, yPosition);
Point localPoint = this.ImageWrap.PointToScreen(mousePosition);
```

Please provide me with suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the panel's [InputHitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.inputhittest.aspx) method. It will return the element at the given position (in coordinates relative to the panel), or `null`, as long as you don't set the panel's Background property.

```
Point screenPosition = new Point(xPosition, yPosition);
Point panelPosition = ImageWrap.PointFromScreen(screenPosition); // not PointToScreen
IInputElement element = ImageWrap.InputHitTest(panelPosition);

if (element is Image)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving a direction. Still trying it out.